# Torch lua function to return multiple values

Tags: python, lua, torch

I would like to replicate the following python function in lua/torch.

```
def add_and_multiply(a,b):
    c=a+b;
    d=a*b;
    return c,d
```

How can I return two values simultaneously in lua/torch as above?
Also, suppose a and b were matrices(with appropriate dimensions), how would the code change for torch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happens in lua too. You can even skip using two extra `local` variables:

```
function add_and_multiply(a,b)
    return a + b, a * b
end
```

Comment: How would this change if we are using arrays instead? Also, for some reason, it isn't allowing me to upvote because I need 15 reputation which I don't know how to get. Sorry

Comment: Can you show the actual code? In lua, you have [tag:lua-table].

Comment: @Sibi Look for easy to answer Python questions, there's plenty of them.